# Angular 2 ngClass: Get Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected when trying to display json on html

Tags: json, angular, angular2-directives, ng-class

I'm new to Angular 2 and was hoping to get some help from the community.  I'm currently trying to implement a dynamic/conditional implementation of ngClass in a `<tr>` element of my html view.  The trufy used is a variable and its original value comes from a JSON object set on my Componenet:

```
<td [ngClass] = "{weak : {{jsonInMyComponenet.element}}, neutral : !{{jsonInMyComponenet.element}}}"  ></td>
```

When I use the code above I get this error:

Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

If I remove the curly brackets I get no errors but the page doesn't render the element, so I can't see the class implementation of weak nor neutral.  What am I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `[...]` and `{{...}}` together. Either the one or the other.

```
<td [ngClass] = "{'weak' : jsonInMyComponenet.element, 'neutral' : !jsonInMyComponenet.element}"  ></td>
```

`{{...}}` is for string interpolation. `[...]` interprets the value as expression.

Comment: Thank you Gunter, yes I removed it, however the class doesn't render.  It would either have the cell have a background color of red or grey, and it is currently white.

I'm not sure, if maybe my json data is incorrect:
 {
    
        "jsonInMyComponenet": true,
        "jsonInMyComponenet1": false,
        "jsonInMyComponenet2" : true
    
}

Comment: I forgot you need to put the property names in quotes when they are literal names.

Comment: Ok, in this case, how about the ones that should evaluate to false?  I tried '!jsonInMyComponenet.element' and !'!jsonInMyComponenet.element' but is not rendering :(

Comment: Just `!jsonInMyComponenet.element` should do, as shown with `neutral` in my answer.